# Behaviour of restrictions of automorphisms of groups on characteristic subgroup under epimorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product, characteristic-subgroups

Let $G = H \rtimes_\alpha K$, where $H$ is abelian and characteristic in $G$. Let $\phi\in\mathrm{Aut}(G)$, and $\phi'$ is its restriction: $\phi'=\phi\big\rvert_H$.

Let $A = B \rtimes_\beta K$, where $B$ is also abelian and characteristic, and $\pi$ be an epimorphism from $H$ onto $B$. 
I know that (in the case that I am studying) $\psi' = \pi\circ\phi'\circ\pi^{-1}\in\mathrm{Aut}(B)$ is well-defined (actually, $\pi$ is independent of $\phi$, meaning that for every automorphism $\phi'$ of $H$, such $\psi'$ can be constructed and in a unique way).
I also know that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ satisfy
$$
\forall k\in K\enspace \forall h\in H\quad \pi\big(\alpha(k)(h)\big) = \beta(k)(\pi(h)).
$$

Do these conditions imply that $\psi'$ is a restriction of some $\psi\in\mathrm{Aut}(A)$, $\psi\big\rvert_B=\psi'$?

**P. S.** The question is inspired by my work on Reidemeister classes.

Comment: When you say $\psi'$ is well-defined, you mean $\ker(\pi)$ is known to be characteristic in $H$?

Comment: @AndreasCaranti someting close to it, I think. I meant that if $\pi(a) = \pi(b)$, then $\pi\circ\phi'(a) = \pi\circ\phi'(b)$. That is, it is ok to write $\pi^{-1}$.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you are then indeed claiming $\ker(\pi)$ to be characteristic in $G$. In fact, if $a \in \ker(\pi)$, that is $\pi(a) = 1 = \pi(1)$, you get for all automorphisms $\phi$ of $G$ that $\pi(\phi(a)) = \pi(\phi'(a)) = \pi(\phi'(1)) = 1$.

Comment: Then it seems to me that your conditions do indeed imply your statements, as all automorphisms of $G$ induce automorphisms of $A \cong G/\ker(\pi)$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti yes, but you cannot write $\pi(\phi(...))$, because I am not sure about what $\pi$ does to the whole group $G$

Comment: It seems it does not matter, as $a \in \ker(\pi) \le H$, so $\phi'(a) = \phi(a) \in H$ by the definition of restriction to the characteristic subgroup $H$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti so you mean that I should just verify that defining $\Pi:G\rightarrow G$ as $\Pi(h,k) = (\pi(h),k)$ makes it a homomorphism?

Comment: Yes, I have just written it up in an answer.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti thank you, I will examine it a bit later, though it seems to be absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}$I am summing up here what I wrote in the comments above.

The condition on $\pi$ is

> $\pi(a) = \pi(b)$ for $a, b \in H$ implies $\pi(\phi'(a)) = \pi(\phi'(b))$.

This is equivalent to the statement

> $\ker(\pi)$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G$.

In fact, let $a \in \ker(\pi) \le H$, and $\phi \in \Aut(G)$. Since $\pi(a) = 1 = \pi(1)$, we get $\pi(\phi(a)) = \pi(\phi'(a)) = \pi(\phi'(1)) = 1$, that is, $\phi(a) \in \ker(\pi)$.

Conversely, if $\ker(\pi)$ is characteristic, then $\pi(a) = \pi(b)$ implies $a = b k$, for some $k \in \ker(\pi)$, so that $\phi'(a) = \phi'(b) k'$, for $k' = \phi'(k) \in \ker(\pi)$, and $\pi(\phi'(a)) = \pi(\phi'(b) k') = \pi(\phi'(b))$.

Now we claim that
\begin{align*}
\theta :\ &G \to A\\
&(h, k) \mapsto (\pi(h), k)
\end{align*}
is an epimorphism. In fact
\begin{align*}
\theta ((h_{1}, k_{1}) \cdot (h_{2}, k_{2}))
&=
\theta((h_{1} \cdot \alpha(k_{1}) (h_{2}), k_{1} k_{2})
\\&=
(\pi(h_{1} \cdot \alpha(k_{1})(h_{2})), k_{1} k_{2})
\\&=
(\pi(h_{1}) \cdot \pi(\alpha(k_{1})(h_{2})), k_{1} k_{2})
\\&=
(\pi(h_{1}) \cdot \beta(k_{1})(\pi(h_{2})), k_{1} k_{2})
\\&=
(\pi(h_{1}), k_{1}) \cdot (\pi(h_{2}), k_{2})
\\&=
\theta (h_{1}, k_{1}) \cdot \theta(h_{2}, k_{2}),
\end{align*}
where we have used the other assumption

> $\pi\big(\alpha(k)(h)\big) = \beta(k)(\pi(h))$ for $h \in H$, $k \in K$.

Since the kernel $\ker(\pi) \times \Set{1}$ of $\theta$ is characteristic in $G$, all automorphisms of $G$ induce automorphisms of $A$, which yields the required statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation